# UIView Subview Does not autoresize on orientation change

Tags: iphone, uiview, interface-builder, subview

In my iPhone app, I have a view controller with two views (essentially, a front & back view). The front view is the main UIView, and the back view is a secondary UIView which is added as a subview using `[self.view addSubview:backView]` when showing the back and `[backView removeFromSuperview]` when hiding it. However, when the orientation changes, I have the following issue: **the main UIView (frontView) rotates & all of its elements resize properly, but the secondary/subview UIView (backView) does not rotate & all of its elements do not resize properly.** Does anyone have suggestions on how to make the secondary UIView autoresize properly according to the rules I have set in Interface Builder?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the end, the solution I found was simply to separate my UIViews into separate UIViewControllers, and make sure that any views that I wanted to be able to rotate only had one UIView.

Answer (score 1):

If I understand correctly, at the time of rotation 'backView' has been removed from it's superview, yeah?  If so, that's the cause of the problem.  The autoresize property determines how the view resizes relative to it's superview.  If it doesn't have a superview it won't resize.

Perhaps using [backView setHidden:YES] instead of [backView removeFromSuperview] will be sufficient for your needs.

Comment: Unfortunately, this happens even when backView is in the superview too. And I just tried out your suggestion to use `[backView setHidden:YES]` and it didn't do the trick either.

Comment: Is backView.autoresizesSubviews == YES?  Presumably it would be since it's the default, but so far that's the only other thing I can think of.

Comment: Is there a code sample you can post that actually exhibits the incorrect behavior?

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem, here is how I fixed it based on imaginaryboy's
suggestions (thanks!)

Add the backview to the viewcontroller at viewDidLoad and hide it at the same time. Show it when needed, Hide it again. Set the resizing of the backview to UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleWidth in IB (or code I guess, I used IB)

Answer (score 0):

Not that this is the same problem, but I found a similar problem when adding 2 subviews in my application:didFinishLaunchingWithOptions method.  Since your reference above is using [self.view addSubview:*view*], I would understand that to mean that self is not your UIWindow.  When adding an additional view controller to your App Delegate window (UIWindow), the second view controller will NOT receive any rotation events and will never rotate.  Only the first view controller added to UIWindow will rotate.  See:[Technical Q&A QA1688](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#qa/qa2010/qa1688.html)  I believe this also affects views added after the first view where the first view is later removed from the superview.

I ended up following the suggestion I read elsewhere to use separate views for each orientation, thereby eliminating the need to worry about resizing behavior.  As always, YMMV.

Answer (score 0):

Or; if you want to avoid an additional controller, you can achieve the same effect by setting view.frame in willRotateToInterfaceOrientation:: like so

```
    if(UIInterfaceOrientationIsLandscape([[UIApplication sharedApplication] statusBarOrientation])) ;//set stubborn view.frame for landscape orientation

    else ; //set stubborn view.frame for portrait orientation
```

Although it feels like a hack; it's simple.